# Grab header variable in Python

Tags: python, nginx, flask, geoip

I am trying to use the geoip module on nginx and I think I have set everything up correctly, but my problem is the tutorial I am working with is in PHP and I am working with Python Flask.

This is the PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>What is my IP address - determine or retrieve my IP address</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <?php
     $country_code = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE);
    echo "<br/>Your country : $country_code";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Specifically this line:

```
$country_code = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE);
```

What would be the equvalent Python code to do the same thing? This is the tutorial I was working from if that helps: [LINK](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-geoip-module-configuration/)

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing how you're running your Python app. Are you using a framework? CGI? WSGI? What?

Comment: Yup it says above, python flask running on nginx. I didnt meantion that Im running it through UWSGI but I dont think that is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent python/flask code could be:

```
from flask import request
country_code = request.environ.get('GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a view, with a template, such as:

`request.environ` will get the value from the WSGI environment

Your view:

```
@app.route('/show-country-code/')
def get_my_ip():
    return render_template('show-country-code.html', country_code=request.environ['the_name_of_the_var'])
```

Your `show-country-code.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>What is my IP address - determine or retrieve my IP address</title>
 </head>
<body>
    <p>Your country code is: {{ country_code }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```